# how to read aT Username Multi Lua

Tags: string, lua, match

I'm new to the Lua .. I want to get the username , using `string.match`

That's like the way I use them

```
local text = 'hi my name @saleh and my friend @chris ..'
print(string.match(text, "(@[%a%d]+)"));
```

Result

```
@saleh
```

I want all the usernames

Comment: OK, what's wrong with what you have? Doesn't that get the job done?

Comment: @NicolBolas i want to bring all the results usernames ,, example:`@saleh @chris`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`string.gmatch`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-string.gmatch). Use it in a loop:

```
for name in text:gmatch "(@[%a%d]+)" do
    print( name )
end
```

Comment: Actually, the required pattern is even simpler: '@%w+'

Comment: @tonypdmtr `%w` also includes `_` character.

Comment: Well, it doesn't!  Try it: "for s in ('Hello_World'):gmatch '%w+' do print(s) end". And, if it did, the documentation would be wrong.

Comment: @tonypdmtr Ah, damn! A million languages, each with different regex flavours :/

Answer (score 0):

above answer not work

This code is exact

```
for name in text:gmatch "(@[%a%d]+)" do
    print(name:sub(2, -1))
end
```